# Pycharm: Struggling to properly structure project folders

Tags: python, pycharm, structure, python-poetry

First of all, the doc related to my problem is [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-project-structure.html) but it's not that helpful

I created a very simple project that I want to package with poetry. It contains:

A library, named `mylib`, that contains a single package, `tools`, that contains a single module, `lists.py`

According to `Pycharm` doc, the library is put under an `src` directory, which is marked as a source folder, and has no `__init__.py` file. When we do that,`Pycharm` extends the system path with the *./src* folder

There's also a test folder, that contains a test file, to test the two functions that exists in the code.

It looks like this:

[image]

I build the project with poetry, the problem with that is that `Poetry` has no idea that the `src` directory is added in the path (actually, the problem would be the exact same with any wheel or any python interpreter started out of `Pycharm`), and so, namespaces are not resolvable.

**Once build, the entry point is not usable. `Pytest` too is not able to run the tests from the command line.**

Now I could do the opposite, have no `src` module and simply place the `mylib` folder at the root, and everything would work python wise, but I would not be able to use `Pycharm` feature of sources folder.

**So my question basically is: how do you structure your packages in order to have both a valid `Pycharm` folder structure, and a valid python folder structure**

Code is added there for reproduction:

**list.py:**

```
"""This module contains a collection of list tools"""
from typing import List

def merge_two_lists(target: List, source: List) -> List:
    """Merge two lists

        - Values that do not exist in the target list  will be added to it
        - Values that exist in the target list will not be duplicated

    Args:
        target (List): Merge target, will be returned once the merge is completed
        source (List): Merge source, will not be modified at the end of the merge

    Returns:
        The modified target list.
    """

    if source is None:
        return target

    target = target + [x for x in source if x not in target]
    return target


def substract_two_lists(target: List, source: List) -> List:
    """Substract two lists

        - Values that both exist in target and source will be removed

    Args:
        target (List): Substraction target, will be returned once the merge is completed
        source (List): Substraction source, will not be modified at the end of the merge

    Returns:
        The modified target list.
    """

    if source is None:
        return target

    target = [x for x in target if x not in source]
    return target


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(merge_two_lists([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

**test_merges_and_substraction.py:**

```
import pytest

from mylib.tools.lists import merge_two_lists, substract_two_lists


def test_that_distinct_lists_can_be_merged():
    target = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    source = ['d', 'e', 'f']

    target = merge_two_lists(target, source)

    assert target == ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']


def test_that_when_lists_are_merged_common_values_are_not_duplicated():
    target = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    source = ['a', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'c']

    target = merge_two_lists(target, source)

    assert target == ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']


def test_that_distinct_lists_can_be_substracted():
    target = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    source = ['d', 'e', 'f']

    target = substract_two_lists(target, source)

    assert target == ['a', 'b', 'c']


def test_that_when_lists_are_substracted_common_values_are_removed():
    target = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    source = ['a', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'c']

    target = substract_two_lists(target, source)

    assert target == []


@pytest.mark.parametrize("source", [None, []])
def test_that_list_merge_is_robust_to_none(source):
    target = ['a', 'b', 'c']

    target = merge_two_lists(target, source)

    assert target == ['a', 'b', 'c']


@pytest.mark.parametrize("source", [None, []])
def test_that_list_substraction_is_robust_to_none(source):
    target = ['a', 'b', 'c']

    target = substract_two_lists(target, source)

    assert target == ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

**pyproject.toml:**

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "toto"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Me <me@gmail.com>"]
readme = "README.md"

packages = [
    { include = "src/mylib/tools" },
]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

[tool.poetry.scripts]
run_merge = 'mylib.tools.lists:main'

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "*"
```

Comment: just do include=src i think ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

poetry defaults to expecting a flat layout (one without `src`). If you want to use a src layout then you have to tell poetry where to find each *top-level* package (it will discover subpackages from there on in. For example:

```ini
packages = [
    { include = "mylib", from = "src" },
]
```

See [here](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/src-layout-vs-flat-layout/) for a more detailed explnation of flat vs src layouts.

You'll also need to tell pytest where to look for your top-level packages. So add the following section to `pyproject.toml`

```ini
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
pythonpath = [
  "src"
]
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked, and I did not have to make changes for pytest